# ReactiveUI observing Collection with WhenAny and assigning boolean PropertyHelper

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, reactiveui

I have an ObservableCollection containing strings that I want to observe. When there is a change in the first index I want to update a ObservableAsPropertyHelper boolean variable and set it to true if the string at that index is not null and not empty. Alternatively a way to convert the Collection into an second ObservableCollection containing bools would also be ok.
Here is what I tried:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Difficulties { get; set; }
public extern bool Easy { [ObservableAsProperty] get; }

public Song()
{
    this.WhenAny(x => x.Easy, x => x.GetValue()[0] != null && x.GetValue()[0}]!= "").ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.Easy);
}
```

I tried the code above because it worked for a similar example:

```
[Reactive] public string Title { get; set; }
public extern bool Enabled { [ObservableAsProperty] get; }

public Song()
{
   this.WhenAny(x => x.Title, x => x.GetValue() != null && x.GetValue() != "").ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.Enabled);
}
```

I am pretty new to using Linq expressions so the solution is probably easy (much easier that the stuff I have tried -_-)
I am using ReactiveUi.WPF and ReactiveUi.Fody on .net core 3.0 by the way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `WhenAnyValue` extension method is typically used for cases when you'd like to observe changes of view model properties and is excellent in doing just that. It wasn't designed to work with mutable collections, such as `ObservableCollection` or `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`. For reactive collections, use the [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData) library, see the related [documentation page](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/) as well. Newest ReactiveUI versions have a dependency on DynamicData, so you don't have to install any additional packages.

TLDR;

1. If you have a property of type `T`, then use `WhenAnyValue`.
2. If you have a property of type `ObservableCollection<T>`, use `ToObservableChangeSet`.

```cs
[ObservableAsProperty] 
public bool Easy { get; }

public ObservableCollection<string> Difficulties { get; }

public Song()
{
    Difficulties = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    // Observe any changes in the observable collection.
    // Note that the property has no public setters, so we 
    // assume the collection is mutated by using the Add(), 
    // Delete(), Clear() and other similar methods.
    this.Difficulties
        // Convert the collection to a stream of chunks,
        // so we have IObservable<IChangeSet<TKey, TValue>>
        // type also known as the DynamicData monad.
        .ToObservableChangeSet(x => x)
        // Each time the collection changes, we get
        // all updated items at once.
        .ToCollection()
        // If the collection isn't empty, we access the
        // first element and check if it is an empty string.
        .Select(items => 
            items.Any() &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items.First()))
        // Then, we convert the boolean value to the
        // property. When the first string in the
        // collection isn't empty, Easy will be set
        // to True, otherwise to False.
        .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.Easy);
}
```

Note, that if you are using immutable data sets, for example somewhat like this:

```cs
[Reactive] public IEnumerable<string> Difficulties { get; set; }
```

and that data set is updated only through its public setter, then you should use the `WhenAnyValue` extension method here, as the collection declared as `IEnumerable<string>` isn't observable:

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Difficulties)
    .Select(items => 
        items.Any() &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items.First()))
    .ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.Easy);
```

Comment: Great answer, and that TL;DR was a real eye-opener for me!